# Log-likelihood skew-t

Tags: multivariate-analysis, likelihood, skewness

I am trying to write down the log-likelihood for the **multivariate skewed student-t** distribution, but I don't really get how to define it exactly. Could someone please tell me the definition as in how it is written down? I am using the following *univariate skewed student-t* (see below). I believe that it follows from: *Fernandez, C., Steel, M.F. (1998). On Bayesian Modeling of Fat Tails and Skewness. Journal of the American Statistical Association, Taylor & Francis Group, 93(441), 359--371.* [image]

Comment: Because there are various different ways even to define a *univariate* skewed $t$ distribution, there is no definite answer to this question.  Do you have some reference or perhaps a clear characterization that would help us know what distribution you are referring to?

Comment: I made some changes to my question, and added for example the definition of univariate student-t that I am using. I hope it is more clear now!

Comment: Where did you obtain (14) and (15)? Those are not from the paper you reference and they contain some typos and other apparent errors.

Comment: I have a document which was shared by my professor at the university. This document contains various univariate distributions, among others the skewed student-t. That documents also has Fernandez & Steel (1998) as reference, and I believe that 14 & 15 are just result of rearrangement. Therefore, equation 14 & 15 should be correct. But now I will need the multivariate form based on this univariate definition.

Comment: As far as I can tell, they are not correct.  They don't agree with the original F&S approach and don't integrate to unity.

Answer (score 1):

Fernandez & Steel describe a simple method to create a skewed version of any *symmetric, unimodal* distribution with density $f:$ split it at its mode ($0$) and scale it by a factor $\gamma$ in the positive direction and $1/\gamma$ in the negative direction.  Clearly the skew is positive for $\gamma \gt 1$ and negative for $\gamma \lt 1.$

Here are plots of the Student $t_2$ density and two skewed versions for $\gamma=3/2$ (red) and $\gamma = 1/2$ (blue).

[image]

A standard way to create a multivariate distribution family out of any univariate distribution $f$ is to apply an arbitrary (usually invertible) affine transformation to a sequence of independent variables with that distribution.  Such a transformation is given by a square matrix $\mathbb A$ and a translation vector $\mu.$  The resulting density at a value $\mathbf x$ is obtained by solving the equation

$$\mathbb A\mathbf y + \mu = \mathbf x,$$

applying the product density to $\mathbf y,$ and dividing by the absolute value of the determinant of $\mathbb A$ (coming from the Jacobian of the transformation).

**The likelihood of a dataset of independent (vector) observations from such a distribution now writes itself:** choose your favorite notation to describe the Fernandez & Steel procedure, apply the affine transform, and take the product of the resulting probabilities.  (I can almost guarantee that any reasonable solution will be simpler than the material in the question!).

---

**To make this even clearer in the details and to illustrate the process,** let's begin with `R` code to implement the Fernandez & Steel construction.  The argument `f` of this function is any density for a symmetric unimodal distribution, such as `dnorm`, `dt`, or `dbeta` (assuming its two parameters are equal).  It returns the skew version of the function. The skewness parameter $\gamma$ will be its first argument, followed by any arguments expected by `f`.

```R
skewform <- function(f)
  function(x, gamma, ...)
    ifelse(x >= 0, f(x / gamma, ...), f(x * gamma, ...)) * 2 / (gamma + 1 / gamma)
```

For instance, `f <- skewform(dt); curve(f(x, gamma = 3/2, df = 2), -5, 5)` plots the red curve in the preceding figure.

Next, `mtskew` is the multivariate version of a skewed Student $t$ distribution.  Its argument `x` is an array of column vectors at which the multivariate density is desired.  The remaining arguments are the parameters $\mu$ (the center), $A$ (the transformation), $\gamma$ (the skewness parameter), and $\nu$ (the Student $t$ parameter).

```R
mtskew <- function(x, mu, A, gamma, nu) {
  if (!is.matrix(x)) x <- matrix(x, length(x), 1)
  d <- exp(determinant(A, logarithm = TRUE)$modulus / nrow(x))
  f <- skewform(dt)
  y <- solve(A, x - mu)
  apply(y, 2, \(y) prod(f(y, gamma, nu) / d))
}
```

Numerical integration of some examples confirms that this function is a valid density: it integrates to unity.  I used it to generate this filled contour plot of a 2D skewed multivariate $t$ distribution.

[image]

The white dot near the center locates $\mu.$

The data for this plot (created with the `image` function) were generated by applying `mtskew` to the points on a regular grid of coordinates:

```R
x <- seq(-5, 15, length.out = 201)        # x coordinates
y <- seq(-8, 4, length.out = 201)         # y coordinates
df <- as.matrix(expand.grid(x = x, y = y))# Grid of (x,y) pairs
z <- matrix(mtskew(t(df), c(2, -1), matrix(c(1, -1/2, 1/2, 1/4), 2), 1.5, 12), length(x))
```

As a check, the Riemann sum for these data is very nearly $1$:

`sum(z) * (x[2]-x[1]) * (y[2]-y[1])`

```
 [1] 0.9999982
```

As a further check, repeating the calculation with $\gamma = 1$ (no skewness) and $\nu=\infty$ (reducing to the standard Normal distribution) produces the elliptical contours one would expect of a bivariate Normal distribution with covariance $\mathbb A^\prime \mathbb A:$

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will try to work further for now, based on this.